# Do not exit python program, but keep running

Tags: python

I've seen a few of these questions, but haven't found a real answer yet.

I have an application that launches a gstreamer pipe, and then listens to the data it sends back.

In the example application I based mine one, it ends with this piece of code:

```
gtk.main()
```

there is no gtk window, but this piece of code does cause it to keep running. Without it, the program exits.

Now, I have read about constructs using `while True:`, but they include the `sleep` command, and if I'm not mistaken that will cause my application to freeze during the time of the sleep so ...

Is there a better way, without using gtk.main()?

Comment: Please expound on your requirements... Tell us what you want to accomplish, not the means by which you mean to accomplish it.

Comment: What's wrong with `gtk.main()`?

Answer (score 3):

`gtk.main()` runs an event loop. It doesn't exit, and it doesn't just freeze up doing nothing, because inside it has code kind of like this:

```
while True:
    timeout = timers.earliest() - datetime.now()
    try:
        message = wait_for_next_gui_message(timeout)
    except TimeoutError:
        handle_any_expired_timers()
    else:
        handle_message(message)
```

That `wait_for_next_gui_message` function is a wrapper around different platform-specific functions that wait for X11, WindowServer, the unnamed thing in Windows, etc. to deliver messages like "user clicked your button" or "user hit ctrl-Q".

If you call `http.serve_forever()` or similar on a `twisted`, `HTTPServer`, etc., it's doing exactly the same thing, except it's a `wait_for_next_network_message(sources, timeout)` function, which wraps something like `select.select`, where `sources` is a list of all of your sockets.

If you're listening on a gstreamer pipe, your `sources` can just be that pipe, and the `wait_for_next` function just `select.select`.

Or, of course, you could use a networking framework like `twisted`.

---

However, you don't *need* to design your app this way. If you don't need to wait for multiple sources, you can just block:

```
while True:
    data = pipe.read()
    handle_data(data)
```

Just make sure the pipe is not set to nonblocking. If you're not sure, you can use `setblocking` on a socket, `fcntl` on a Unix pipe, or something I can't remember off the top of my head on a Windows pipe to make sure.

In fact, even if you need to wait for multiple sources, you can do this, by putting a blocking loop for each source into a separate thread (or process). This won't work for thousands of sockets (although you can use greenlets instead of threads for that case), but it's fine for 3, or 30.

Answer (score 1):

I've become a fan of the Cmd class.  It gives you a shell prompt for your programs and will stay in the loop while waiting for input.  Here's the [link to the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html).  It might do what you want.

Comment: I always forget about `cmd`, until right after I've built 70% of it myself (about once every year or two), so thanks for the reminder! However, his program needs to listen to the data on a pipe, and `cmd` isn't going to help with that.